# ActiveRecord Table definition type for repeating count

Tags: database, database-design, activerecord, database-connection

I'm setting up a table for a class scheduling app.  The class will only have 8 seats available each calendar month.

Within my table I need help with the ActiveRecord type I should select that will auto_increment up to 8 and then stop for any given month

I also need help with the ActiveRecord type I should select for month.  Should I employ the same idea for class seats and have this number stop at 12 (for december) and refresh back to 1 (assuming of course I include a year attribute in my table)

thanks,
MO12

Answer (score 0):

I would put the 8-seat maximum logic into your application, and not your database.

You probably want two tables: `classes` and `seats`. Since `class` is a reserved word you should use something like SchoolClass:

```
class SchoolClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :seats, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school_class
end
```

To validate that the maximum number of seats has been reached, use a combination of a before filter and an instance method. Something like this:

```
class SchoolClass
  MAXIMUM_SEATS = 8

  before_create :validate_limit

  def limit_reached?
    seats.count >= MAXIMUM_SEATS
  end

  private
  def validate_limit
    errors.add :base, "The maximum of this class has been reached" if limit_reached?
  end
end
```

Lastly using two integer columns for year and month is a good idea. You probably want to add an index across these columns as well.